# If $f'(x)=1+f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$ prove that $f(x) = e^x -1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable.
Also let $f'(x)=1+f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$

How to prove that $f(x) = e^x -1$?

---

**My Approach**

- $f'(x) = (e^x -1)' = e^x \iff \boxed{f(x) = e^x +c} \quad (1) $
- $f(0)=0 \iff f(0) = e^0 +c=0 \iff 1+c = 0\iff \boxed{c=-1} \quad (2)$

Hence $f(x) = e^x -1$

---

I don't like this proof because it begins with the hypothesis $f(x) = e^x -1$. Suppose we didn't know the result from the start, how could we derive to it by using only that: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, differentiable. And $f'(x)=1+f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$

Comment: This is just a seperable ODE. Why not solve it as normal?

Comment: Yes @PeterForeman. Its just $\int{\frac{df(x)}{1+f(x)}}=\int{dx}$

Comment: @DatBoi We just need to assume that $f(x)\not\equiv -1$ which is obvious from the initial condition.

Comment: Yes of course !

Comment: If I were to guess, @PeterForeman the OP might not be in the ODE class, they might be given this question in a Calculus class.

Comment: Use Laplace Transform : it's so easy in such a cases !

Comment: Ahhhh indeed its an ODE. @ArcticChar Many of my math.exchange questions are about way more difficult ODE's. It almost funny I didn't notice this one. Thank you all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already told in the previous answer, this can be solved by just dividing $\ f(x)+1 $ and then integrating. One more method comes to mind:
$$\ f'(x)=f(x)+1$$
$$\ f'(x)-f(x)=1$$
$$\ {e}^{-x}f'(x)-{e}^{-x}f(x)={e}^{-x}$$
$$\ \frac{d}{dx} {e}^{-x}f(x)={e}^{-x}$$
$$\ {e}^{-x}f(x) = -{e}^{-x}+C$$
$$\ f(x)=C{e}^{x}-1 $$
Find $\ C=1$ by using $\ f(0)=0$.
Hope it helps!

**EDIT**: This is a general trick(manipulation) used that whenever there is a $\ f'(x)+Kf(x)$, multiply and divide by $\ {e}^{Kx} $ so that the expression reduces to $$\ {e}^{-Kx}\frac{d}{dx} {e}^{Kx}f(x)$$

Answer (score 4):

So you have $${dy\over dx} =1+y$$ Rewrite it like this $${dy\over 1+y} = dx$$ and now integrate both sides.