# Continuous and differentiable function on $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Suppose f is continuous on $[0, \infty)$, differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and $f(0) \geq 0$. Suppose $f'(x) \geq f(x)$ for all x $ \in (0,\infty)$. Then $f(x) \geq 0$ for all x $ \in (0,\infty)$.**

---

Can we conclude with the help of the method of contradiction and intermediate value theorem for continuous function?

Comment: I don't think that works. A hint is to consider $(e^{-x}f(x))'$

Comment: Thanks! the given hint works.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804843/if-fx-1fx-and-f0-0-prove-that-fx-ex-1/3804852#3804852

Look at the edit or the hint present at the end of the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ f'(x) \geq f(x) $$
$$\ f'(x)-f(x) \geq 0$$
$$\ {e}^{-x}f'(x)-{e}^{-x}f(x) \geq 0$$
$$\ \frac{d}{dx} {e}^{-x}f(x) \geq 0$$
This implies that $\ {e}^{-x}f(x) $ is increasing.
Therefore, $$\ {e}^{-x}f(x) \geq {e}^{-0}f(0)=0, x \geq 0$$
Hence, $$\ f(x) \geq 0, \forall x\geq 0$$
Hope it helps!